# sum the odd numbers in line form file.txt bash

Tags: bash

hello the StackOverflow i wanted to ask you how to sum the odd numbers in every line from input file.txt

> the input.txt file looks like that

```
4 1 8 3 7 
2 5 8 2 7 
4 7 2 5 2 
0 2 5 3 5 
3 6 3 1 6
```

> the output must be

```
11
12
12
13
7
```

start of the code like this

```
read -p "Enter file name:" filename

    while read line
    do
...
```

my code whats the wrong here

```
#!/bin/sh
    read -p "Enter file name:" filename

    while read line
    do
    sum = 0
    if ($_ % 2 -nq 0){
        sum = sum + $_
    }
    echo $sum
    sum = 0
    done <$filename
```

Comment: I've edited the output sample as the last line's sum was incorrect (3+3+1=7). Please revert my edit if I misunderstood something

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment. If it is - shouldn't you do it by yourself instead of letting others do the work for you?  ;-)

Comment: while read line
 do 
  echo $line > file17
  awk '[for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i % 2==0)$i=" "} END{print $0}' file17 >> odd
  awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++}if($i % 2==1)$i=" "} END{print $0}' file17 >> even
 done < $1
 cat odd >> odd1
 cat even >> odd1
 n=0
 lines='wc -1 < odd'
 while read line
 do
n='expr $n + 1'
ifodd='expr $n % 2'
if test $ifodd -eq 1
then
echo 'tail -$lines odd |head -1'>> evenodd
else
if test $ifodd -eq 0
then 
echo 'tail -$lines even |head -1'>> evenodd
lines = 'expr $lines -1'
fi
fi
done < odd1
cat evenodd
rm odd1
rm evenodd
rm odd
rm even
fi

Comment: @YassinMrd edit your question reflecting the code instead of adding it to the comment section please.

Comment: i tried and it not working it not homework it is for preparing i know how to do sum for odd and even numbers but line but line i don't know

Comment: Given your format you can use word-splitting and a for loop : `for number in $line; do echo "$number"; done` ([try it here](https://ideone.com/cWE7wh)). Use that inside your while loop

Comment: `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=$i*($i%2)};print s;s=0} $filename`

Comment: Your question is tagged bash, your code uses a sh shebang and a mix of bash and csh? syntax, the answers use PowerShell... I'm confused.

Comment: This question might be beyond salvation at this point. For those wondering why there are 2 `powershell` answers to this question, note that the `powershell` tag was included before the question was edited in addition to that `if` statement which is clearly `powershell` syntax and not `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic seems correct in your question, so I'll go with *you're not sure how to do this line by line as stated on your comment*.

```
if ($_ % 2 -nq 0){
    sum = sum + $_
}
```

I think it's a good place for a `function` in this case. Takes a `string` containing `integers` as input and returns the sum of all odd numbers on that string or `-1` assuming there are no integers or all even numbers.

```
function Sum-OddNumbers {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Line
    )

    process {
        [regex]::Matches($Line,'\d+').Value.ForEach{
            begin {
                $result = 0
            }
            process {
                if($_ % 2) {
                    $result += $_
                }
            }
            end {
                if(-not $result) {
                    return -1
                }
                return $result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@'
4 1 8 3 7 
2 5 8 2 7 
4 7 2 5 2 
0 2 5 3 5 
3 6 3 1 6
2 4 6 8 10
asd asd asd
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Sum-OddNumbers
```

**Result**

```
11
12
12
13
7
-1
-1
```

Comment: @AbrahamZinala hehe, can't resist this fun exercises :)

Comment: first only what i have to do is to write in command line .\code.sh 
then i got to write the name of txt file 
the input us a txt file name when i compile it i have to write the name of file 
then the code must do its work but yours the output not correct there is -1 -1 at the end and the not properly need function because the logic here is the only condition of variable is odd that's all ???

Comment: @YassinMrd You included the `powershell` tag on your question, hence why I posted a `poswershell` answer. `shell` is not compiled by the way, it is a scripting language and command language.

Comment: isn't the same because i use PowerShell to compile the bash files ?

Answer (score 1):

If that's how your txt file is set up, you can use `Get-Content` and a bit of logic to accomplish this.

- `Get-Content` will read the file line by line (*unless `-Raw` is specified*), which we can pipe to a `Foreach-Object` to have the current line in the iteration *split*  by the white space.
- Then, we can evaluate the newly formed array (*due to splitting the white space, leaving the numbers to create an array*).
- Finally, just get the sum of the odd numbers.

```
Get-Content -Path .\input.txt | ForEach-Object {
    # Split the current line into an array of just #'s
    $OddNumbers = $_.Split(' ').Trim() | Foreach {
        if ($_ % 2 -eq 1) { $_ } # odd number filter
    }
    # Add the filtered results
    ($OddNumbers | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but
not even helpful i m getting errors to compile it ,
and when i did while reading line 
it must be simple why do you want to split it since we read line by line?

Comment: Why would you compile it? With what? PowerShell is an interpreted scripting language. Read my answer to include the bullets again. When you use `Get-Content` each line is passed one at a time as a *string*. Therefore you can't work with it as youre intending to do by getting the sum of the odd numbers. When you split the line (*string*), it creates an array of numbers which we filter by odd numbers, and get the sum.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala see my last comment on the question's comment section. don't even bother too much.

Comment: @Santi, ahhh. Gotcha. Welp, in out lol

Answer (score 1):

"what's wrong here":

```sh
    while read line
    do
    sum = 0
    if ($_ % 2 -nq 0){
        sum = sum + $_
    }
    echo $sum
    sum = 0
    done <$filename
```

First, in `sh`, spaces are not allowed around the `=` in an assigmnent

Next the `if` syntax is wrong. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-if

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic